# Handle Scrolls in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple quiz using ionic with angular. I need to display one card at a one time(Like instagram, facebook). It means when we scroll down the app one card should be rendered on the user view on the mobile phone.
Now my apps look like this.

[image]

I want to apply for only one card when the user uses the app. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you try https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of ionic you're using take a look at:

ionic version 3-5:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Or version 6:
https://swiperjs.com/angular

With some configuration either should work.